# Grails Custom Scaffolding get access to controller name

Tags: grails

I am trying to write a custom `src/templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy` and was wondering if there was any way to get access to the controller name?    Right now it seems like you can only get the "model" class.  The reason I need it is I am customizing the render to prefix the templates directory based on the controller.

For instance I have a controller named `AuthorAdminController` and I need to customize the `list` to use the `/admin/user/**` directory.

Let me know if you have any questions. I am getting ready to look into how to customize `DefaultGrailsTemplateGenerator` but I am not sure if that is the correct route to go.

Example:

```
class UserAdminController {
      static scaffold = User 
}
```

Currently in my `Controller.groovy` I get className='user' so I have no access to the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can, as the way scaffolding works your template will *always* be generating a class named *DomainClassName*Controller (i.e. `UserController` in your example), which gets loaded into a new classloader and then the metaclass of the real controller (`UserAdminController`) gets new actions added to it which delegate to an instance of the generated `UserController`.

Now every controller has access to the `controllerName` property during execution of actions, so this may provide you with a workaround.  I haven't tried it, but you could try putting a `log.info("controller: \${controllerName}")` into the template and see which name it gives you (the backslash to make it resolve at runtime rather than generation time).